# Replace line by string or create new one if doesn't exist - sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to replace 'DUMP=' line or add new line if doesn't exist within a certain block. When block define by from `[text]` until the next `[text]`, for example:

```
[name]
  sometext=...
  moretext=...
  DUMP=
  moretext2=...    
[name2]
  ...
```

For replacing existing line I will do:

```
sed -i '/^\['name'\]$/,/^\[/!b
    /DUMP=/cDUMP=example' $file
```

I don't know if it is possible in one liner or two, but how do I add  the option to add `DUMP=...` if it doesn't exists in that block?

Example 1:

`file1.txt`:

```
[name]
  A=text1
  B=text2
  DUMP=x
  C=text3

[name2]
  A=text12
  B=text22
  DUMP=x2
  C=text32
```

`sed '/^\['name'\]$/,/^\[/!b
    /DUMP=/cDUMP=example' file1.txt` output:

```
[name]
  A=text1
  B=text2
  DUMP=example
  C=text3

[name2]
  A=text12
  B=text22
  DUMP=x2
  C=text32
```

Example 2:

`file1.txt`:

```
[name]
  A=text1
  B=text2
  C=text3

[name2]
  A=text12
  B=text22
  DUMP=x2
  C=text32
```

`sed '/^\['name'\]$/,/^\[/!b
    /DUMP=/cDUMP=example
    <add DUMP incase it doesn't exist>' file1.txt` output:

```
[name]
  A=text1
  B=text2
  C=text3
  DUMP=example

[name2]
  A=text12
  B=text22
  DUMP=x2
  C=text32
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample IO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/^\[/&&/]$/&&s&&!f{print "  DUMP=example"; s=0}
     $0 ~ "^\["blockname"]$"{s=1;f=0}
     s&&/^ *DUMP=/{$0="  DUMP=example"; f=1}
     1
     END{if(s&&!f)  print "  DUMP=example"; } blockname="name" <file>
```

Here, we did the following:

- The variable `s` checks if the correct block is found
- The variable `f` checks if in the correct block, the entry `DUMP=` is found
- **`/^\[/&&/]$/&&s&&!f{print "  DUMP=example"; s=0}`::** If we enter a new block, and the previous block was the correct one (`s==1`) and that block did not have a `DUMP=` entry (`f==0`), write one.
- **`s&&/^ *DUMP=/{$0="  DUMP=example"; f=1}`::** If we are in the correct block (`s==1`), and we find a `DUMP=` entry, update it.

Comment: Those assumptions are wrong, spaces are allowed. I just re-edit my Q so it will be clearer. Plus the result shouldn't effect `[name2]`.

Comment: @Nir your question is not clear. From this I understood that you want to update all DUMPs, but your comment indicates only the first (?) or only the DUMP from a particular block. And when do you want the DUMP to be added.

Comment: @Nir I have updated the answer to my best understanding.